# Java enterprise application missing resources?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, browser, web-applications, java-ee-8

I have a java web app (Java ee) which is Servlet with JSP. Problem im having is that sometimes when i go to browser i wont find the resources that i have added, like some .jsp files will be missing completely and/or missing parts. If i refresh multiple times or if i delete a .jsp file and then add it again with the exact same code it temporarily fixes the problem.

I have tried doing ctr + F5 to clear the cache from browser, but didnt work. I also tried removing cache from intellij IDEA, also didnt work. What is going on?

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Hi, i dont know how im supposed to show a minimal exmaple. Its literally just as it sounds, literally a jsp file parts like an element might be there or might not, sometimes it doesnt recognize at all.

Comment: Create and share a project on GitHub, provide the steps to reproduce the issue so that others can try it. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html.